# In what situations is relative preferable over absolute positioning (or vice versa)?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm designing a website and can't decide what type of positioning is better, relative or absolute. I know in the past when I've used absolute positioning and tried to re-size my browser it throws off the position of whatever I'm placing. However, if I use relative positioning and want to change something it always seems to throw everything else on the page off.

What do you professionals out there use?

Comment: Better in terms of what?

Comment: Pretty sure this will get closed. It's completely subjective.

Comment: I'd absolutely use absolute but it's all kinda relative. There's no right answer to this question.

Comment: nice paradox there @Tom.  Anyway, none is more "professional", they are both useful in different situations.  To make absolute positioning more useful, you can set all containing elements to relative, so that absolute positioned elements are positions relative to the relative positioned element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave everything static (relative) by default. This lets things resize a little when the browser size changes. Absolute positioning (relative to the whole webpage) tends to make a webpage stop working properly when the window size changes.

It is however always useful to use absolute position in certain cases. However, set absolute elements relative to other elements - never use absolute positioning relative to the page.

Absolute positioning let's you put certain elements on top of others, for example:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px">
  <img src="" width="100" height="100">
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0">Some text on top</div>
<div>
```

In the above example, the browser positions the absolutely positioned div relative to something. That something is the first relative ancestor up the DOM hierarchy. So it sees the div above it and positions it at (0,0) relative to that div. And therefore one div is placed above another div, which of course is placed relative to the rest of the page.

Generally, when an absolute element is placed above and relative to another element, it will be on top. If you need to adjust what is in front of other elements, you can use the z-index css property.

Answer (score 1):

1. In general, the best is `position:static`
2. If you want the element to stay at the same position relatively to the window, the best is `position:fixed`
3. If you want the element to stay at the same position relatively to a parent element, the best is `position:absolute` and `position` different than `static` to the parent.
4. If you want to remove an element from the flow of the document, the best are `position:absolute` and `position:fixed`.
5. If you want to move an element up/down/to right/to left but you don't want to affect surrounding elements, the best is `position:relative`
6. If you want to move an element up/down/to right/to left and you want to affect surrounding elements, use margins.
7. If an element is overlapped by another element and you want to see the first one, the best is `position:relative` combined with `z-index`.